# angularjs - improve performance via caching/reusing compiled linked template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

So i am using this library https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview, for displaying a tree and i am using a modal, issue for me is that everytime i open the modal it reloads the entire tree(compile and link all elements).

Is it possible that the linked compiled components stay in cache (since the data for the tree remains the same). whenever i launch the tree within popup it doesn't take as long as it did first time

Comment: It is possible with [UI Router sticky state](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky).